# Navigate from Xamarin Forms to Xamarin Native

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

My problem is that I require the first pages of my app to be Native. I need a way to Navigate from a Xamarin Forms Content Page to the first native pages of the app when a user signs out. Is there anyway of from a Forms page starting a native ViewController (iOS) or starting an Activity (Android). I use custom renderers regularly.

It would be brilliant if I could somehow restart the app or call AppDelegate again or something.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use custom renderers regularly, then you can create a custom view renderer like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/). For example:

In PCL:

```
public class NewView : View
{
}
```

In Android platform, create a layout under /Resources/layout first like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="this is new view." />
  <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:text="change text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create the renderer for `NewView` like this:

```
public class NewViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    private TextView tv;
    private Android.Widget.Button btn;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            var context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
            LayoutInflater minflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
            var view = minflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.newview, this, false);
            tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
            btn = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
            SetNativeControl(view);
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            btn.Click -= Btn_Click;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tv.Text = "Text changed!";
    }
}
```

Finally use this view in `ContentPage` to make it like a page:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:NewView />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

For iOS platform, there should be a method to set the `ViewController` as native control for a view renderer. But I'm not familiar with iOS, you may give a try.