# Implementing a passcode xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin app and I want it to have a passcode to enter the app. I have tried to use this component,
https://components.xamarin.com/view/lock-screen but I don't know why its not working.

In my MainActiviy.cs file (in the Droid project) I tried adding this:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        Locker.OnStart(this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        Locker.OnPause(this);
    }
```

However the app just runs as normal, no lock screen. I tried the other method as well, by creating a passcode-protected Activity by subclassing PasscodeProtectedActivity:(the code is the same as what was in the MainActivity class)

```
public class MyProtectedActivity : PasscodeProtectedActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "myId");
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Using this, I get errors saying "The name TabLayoutResource doesn't exist", "The name ToolbarResource doesn't exist" and "The name LoadApplication doesn't exist"

The MainActivity class uses this

`public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity`

which I cannot do with. So how do I make it work?

**EDIT**:

Following the @GraceFeng's answer, I used Passcode and managed to get the hello button to show, (as is done in the sample code) however when I press the button, instead of showing the passcode screen, I get a System.InvalidCastException at this line

`((LockLogic)Application.Context).PasscodeManager.Show(this);`

Note: LockLogic is the equivalent of the file named App.cs in the sample

Comment: This probably wont work on a Xamarin Forms app. It seems that the PasscodeProtectedActivity is a native android Activity. once LoadApplication() is called, the Xamarin Forms UI is presented to user.

Answer (score 0):

> Using this, I get errors saying "The name TabLayoutResource doesn't exist", "The name ToolbarResource doesn't exist" and "The name LoadApplication doesn't exist"

These properties `TabLayoutResource` and `ToolbarResource`, together with method `LoadApplication` are created in the `FormsAppCompatActivity`, which is a subclass of `AppCompatActivity`. It is **NOT** suggested to modify the `MainActivity` to inherit from your `PasscodeProtectedActivity`, if you want to show a lock screen view, you can try to customize a `ContentView` in XF.

You may refer to this case: [Navigate from Xamarin Forms to Xamarin Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943652/navigate-from-xamarin-forms-to-xamarin-native/45951402#45951402).

Then here you can refer to the source code of [XamarinPasscode](https://github.com/kevinskrei/XamarinPasscode), try to inflate the lock screen view from Android layout resource and implement the logic code inside the your `ViewRenderer`.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. I am trying this but I am confused as to how I would "inflate the lock screen view". I followed your link and created a new class in the PCL project named LockScreen.cs and in the Droid project, created a new layout file and a LockScreenRenderer.cs file

Comment: I have managed to get the Hello button showing (as is done in the sample code) however when I press the button, instead of showing the passcode screen, I get a System.InvalidCastException at this line

     `((LockLogic)Application.Context).PasscodeManager.Show(this);`

Note: LockLogic is the equivalent of the file named App.cs in the sample, I already have an App.cs in my PCL project, if I add another App.cs in the Droid project, i was getting funny errors